# PySpark: explode values in list from struct and delete them from this struct

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a column with a struct, something like this:

```
|properties                |
|[john, doe, 123, foo, bar]|
```

`properties` column type:
`('event_properties', 'struct<name:string,surname:string,id:int,extra_field_1:string,extra_field_2:string')`

and a list of properties:

```
["name", "surname", "id"]
```

I am trying to achieve the following:

1. Extract fields from properties, but only those from the list. In pure Python it could be done with simple loop but I am looking for more Sparky way. I know that I can call `df.withColumn("name", df.properties.name)`
2. Remove extracted fields from the `properties` column to avoid duplication and save some space. PySpark 2, so no way to use `dropFields()`

Desired outcome:

```
|properties|name|surname|id |
|[foo, bar]|john|doe    |123|
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Code

```
# Define a list of columns
include = ["name", "surname", "id"]
exclude = ['extra_field_1', 'extra_field_2']

# Fuction to extract relevant items from the struct field
def get_items(cols):
    return [F.col('properties')[c].alias(c) for c in cols]

# Recreate a struct from the exlcuded fields and 
# assign the remaining columns to the dataframe
df = df.select(F.struct(*get_items(exclude)).alias('properties'), *get_items(include))
```

#### Result

```
df.show()

+----------+----+-------+---+
|properties|name|surname| id|
+----------+----+-------+---+
|{foo, bar}|john|    doe|123|
+----------+----+-------+---+
```

Comment: Thanks, @Shubham, it worked!
To avoid defining extra fields I just wrote another function:
```
def filter_items(cols):
    return [col('properties')[c].alias(c) for c in df.select("properties.*").columns if c not in cols]
``` which does what I need.

Comment: can you help me with how to handle if sometimes fields from `include` are not always in the data? I| am looking for defaulting it to null/None